# PHP - Ncurses - Get current line (cursor position)

Tags: php, ncurses

I'm currently working on a linux shell app (batch tool) using php+ncurses. I'm trying to create a loadingbar thingy but I can't get the function "ncurses_getyx" working. It doesn't return anything. I've tried using the arguments as pointers and tried as returning values, but none seem to work.

Does anyone know how I can retreive the current cursor position in the terminal window?
I'm using PuTTY on Windows 7 to connect to my server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you put the variables you want to equal the y and x values as arguments in the function, and it modifies them to equal the correct values.